# CMS for Schools

Tags: jquery, css, content-management-system

Most of these posts have negative votes, but I'm risking it anyway. I tried to ask for support from some websites, but it's complicated or they want you to pay.

Firs of all, I'm a 16 year old student attending Booker T. Washington. My web design teacher (I can't ask her for help because she doesn't know anything. She was put there because the actual web design teacher left) has asked my friend and me to redo the school's website. www.btwash.org For a school with a web design academy, it looks atrocious.

We have some ideas to make the website more modern: Twitter Feed, FaceBook Page, and a blog-like thing for the administration and possibly the teachers.

I guess I just need to know the gist of things.

- If we go with a CMS, will we be able to code the site ourselves
  still? Do we still code it or do we choose the different plugins?
- Will we still be able to use custom JQuery, CSS, and HTML5?
- How do we make sure each teacher can only update their portion of the website and not change anything else? E.g. A math teacher can only update www.btwash.org/teachers/mathteacher1.
- How do I incorporate the blog into a website?

I'm sorry for all of these questions. They should be helpful for any new user hoping to start using a CMS.

Comment: I personally hate CMSs.. But I am pretty sure wordpress would be the most optimal choice, you can modify permissions and stuff, as you had wanted.. Tons of plugins, and you can edit the code..

Comment: I'm not totally sure of the ins and outs of a CMS. My church's website doesn't use one and it's fine. Maybe I should edit my question to include that.

Comment: CMS are good, don't get me wrong.. But if you want to get into the advanced functions, they somewhat limit you. Use wordpress if you don't want to code it all from scratch.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll look into it. I really don't know enough to program it all from scratch, so CMS it is. I'm going to do more research into the different CMS's: Joomla, Wordprss, and Drupal. What are some of the "advanced features" that you're talking about?

Comment: I'm seeing why you hate it. It seems like a lot of freedom is taken away from you. I installed WordPress and it won't recognize my web pages.

Comment: exactly. But as far as CMSs go, wordpress, in my opinion, is better than Drupal and Joomla.

Comment: I feel like I need to use a CMS for what we need to do, but going about it is going to be hard. Am I able to create my own layout for Wordpress? I'm used to straight up coding. No WYSIWYG or CMS interface.

Comment: Yea, I get what you're saying, I do everything myself in the default windows notepad. Creating your own theme requires good knowledge of PHP along with HTML/CSS. If you want to go this route, which I highly suggest, check out the codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: I use Dreamweaver, but I only use the code editor. lol. I'm going to look into it, but I'm starting to think that it may be better to have a sub-domain for the teachers and administration. Maybe blog.btwash.org or news.btwash.org and I can code the main pages how I'm used to and have the sub-domain for the blog.

Comment: Yea, that's an idea. Or you could make a blog and use a php include to make it look like its on the main site, and avoid even having to link to the subdomain.

Comment: I've used the PHP include for organization (navbar.php, header.php, etc). I've thought about using an include, but I didn't want to use iFrames. How do I do the PHP include for this case? I think it'll help a lot because I'm not sure if our school's hosting company allows a sub-domain. (Because I'm a student, they don't let us have all of the information.)

Comment: You don't need it in a subdomain. It can just be installed in a directory called /blog. You could then make a 'blog' page on your non-CMS site, and include the blog as if it wasn't even on the CMS.. That's what most people do. Alternatively, you could also just load it with JQuery rather than php.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm getting a book on it. It's too confusing trying to Google every question I have then have to Google another question based upon what I just read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go with a CMS, will we be able to code the site ourselves still? Do we still code it or do we choose the different plugins?

It depends on the CMS. Most are very customizable. I suggest an open source one those you definitely can code yourselves (assuming you understand the code to begin with) There are quite a few clean and simple ones to understand and modify out there. Sorry but none come to mind at the moment. I came across one a couple of days ago. I'll try to search my history for it and update this post if i find it.

Will we still be able to use custom JQuery, CSS, and HTML5?
Again, it depends on the CMS. I don't understand really how this is different from the first question. I'm assuming you're asking about these specific languages?  That would depend on how your server is set up.  If the CMS requires php, you'll need to install php on your server or the CMS won't work.

The CMS should match up with how you server's set up. So if you want to use Jquery, find a CMS that is developed with it. If you want to use PHP find a CMS developed with php.

HTML5 is just ubiquitous these days. you don't have to worry about that at all.

How do we make sure each teacher can only update their portion of the website and not change anything else?

The benefit of having a CMS is that most of the coding to manage accounts and restrictions are done for you.  Once you've picked a CMS you usually just log into a control panel with an administrator account and manage privileges/restrictions/access.  Read the CMS description for options. as some give you more control than others.

How do I incorporate the blog into a website?
You're going to have to be a bit more specific with this question...

edit: I looked through my history, and I couldn't find the site I was talking about. (it had a list of CMSs and had a comparison of each.  but I DID remember the name of one of the CMSs it was CakePHP or CakeCMS.  it's not that I remembered it because it was any good or because of it's features, but because simply the name stuck out.  But It's a good starting point. good luck!

Comment: Sorry. The second question was supposed to be with the first to clarify what I was asking. I know a little bit of PHP. I use it for organization (header.php, navbar.php, etc) and for forms. 

When I said how do I incorporate the blog: When I used Wordpress as a blog, they really limited you with what you could do. This could also be because it was the blog. I'm installing XAMPP again for this site and installing WordPress and mess with it. 

Oh yeah! Some plugins require a fee just for WordPress. Why is this?

Comment: XAMPP now includes a CMS installer, so this will help.

Comment: I find that lesser known CMS's tend to be more customizable than the big names like wordpress.  My guess is because the big names like wordpress probably want more quality control and similar experience. Search a little more and find one that fits your needs better.

There could be many reasons why a plugin requires fees just for wordpress. It's not something anybody other than the plugin creator can answer.  It's like why does whatsapp charge for android but not ios? probably some deal they have. Who knows? Probably just them.

Comment: Well, the school basically screwed my friend and I over. Apparently they're going to go to some new CMS called School Loop. I can't wait to find the security vulnerabilities. I haven't messed with a VMS that much because I like straight coding better and my client is paying me a monthly upkeep fee, so I can just edit the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new in Webdevelopment too. Because of this i used already many CMS, like Joomla, Drupal. But now i'm testing WolfCMS [WolfMCS](http://www.wolfcms.org/). Just try it out : It's simple, leight-weight and fast, ;). And i think Noobs like me best practice with this. But i'm learning now Javascript and Jquery and want test for my usage in jQuery builded CMS's. After this i can answer you too, which one is the best. But it depends on your usage perhaps, :).

Comment: this is like a comment not an answer

Comment: you are right. so delete and then add as comment, right?